# Как сделать так, чтобы нажатие клавиши enter отображалось в строке при вводе через input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я ввожу строку со всевозможными символами: цифрами, буквами, и, собственно, символами-разделителями (_.,;:\n\t!?), по которым затем моя строка будет дробиться на список переменных строкового типа.

Беда заключается в том, что клавиша enter, которая, по идее, должна отвечать за перенос текста(\n), в отличие от клавиши tab (\t), при нажатии во время ввода в консоли, во-первых, не отображается во вводимой строке, во-вторых, отправляет ее на дальнейшую обработку, завершая при этом ввод с клавиатуры.

UPD: Попробовал с sys.stdin.read() - результат на втором скриншоте. Теперь в список не попадает та часть строки, которая отделяется enter-ом :(

Код:

```
import re
s = input("Введите строку: ")
print(re.split("[_.,;:\t!?]", s))
```

[image: Вот как это выглядит, если выкинуть \n из split-а. Все работает]

[image: 2]

Comment: Код следует вставлять текстом.

Comment: import re

s = input("Введите строку: ")
print(re.split("[_.,;:\t!?]", s))

Вот код
Извиняюсь, что криво - что в вопросе, что в комментарии он почему-то пишется в одну строку автоматически

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос нажав ссылку "Править" под вопросом.

Comment: можно заменить `input()` на `sys.stdin.read()` и завершать ввод комбинацией `Ctrl+D`, но правильнее будет вводить построчно в цикле и завершать, например, пустой строкой.

Comment: @Spatz Вот, попробовал по вашему совету, теперь такая вот беда. Я так понимаю, программа закидывает в список "пустоту" из той же строчки, где я начинал печатать. Если так, то как сделать, чтобы она обратила свое внимание на следующую строку?

Comment: И всё-равно - зачем это всё? Если вы сами с собой договариваетесь, то договоритесь просто на другой символ-разделитель. Или чисто теоретический интерес?

Comment: @ГлебГолубенко пожалуйста, вставляйте всё текстом. И попробуйте добавить флаг `re.MULTILINE` так `re.split("[_.,;:\t!?]", s, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @CrazyElf не, я пытаюсь лабораторную сделать) Писать ее разрешается на любом языке программирования, и, поскольку я во всех был одинаково чайник, сделал выбор в пользу того из них, который больше других был у меня до этого на слуху :D
Что  же до условия задачи, то оно выглядит следующим образом: выделить в строке-предложении s все слова, разделенные символами-разделителями «_.,;:\n\t!?». Обработать выделенные слова в соответствии с вариантом задания (Напечатать слово, содержащее наибольшее количество цифр. Напечатать количество слов, содержащих хотя бы два арифметических знака)

Comment: Судя по формулировке задания, может вам `input` то и не нужен, достаточно просто жёстко задать в коде мультистроковую переменную `s = """ .... """`

Comment: @CrazyElf я тоже об этому думал, но это выглядит странно на фоне того, что во всех предыдущих заданиях требовался ввод с клавиатуры
Да и теперь, когда я уже несколько часов подряд гуглил и даже зарегистрировался тут, чтобы попросить помощи у тех, кто разбирается, не реализовать этот ввод с клавиатуры будет как минимум досадно :/

Comment: @Spatz ничего не изменилось, к сожалению - принт так же выводит "пустоту" в конце списка, хотя переделал re.split по вашему образцу